# Accessing Flickr API methods

Tags: python, api, flickr

I am trying to create a script that downloads Flickr images based on tags. I have found such scripts online, however they don't work because my script can't access the Flickr API functions.

```
import flickr_api


print(flickr_api.__version__)
api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
api_secret = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'

flickr = flickr_api.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret)
photos = flickr.photos.search(user_id='73509078@N00', per_page='10')
```

The result I get is:

```
0.6.1
AttributeError: module 'flickr_api' has no attribute 'FlickrAPI'
```

I'm confused because the API documentation contains  almost this same piece of code (https://stuvel.eu/flickrapi-doc/2-calling.html )

Am I installing the API wrong, somehow?

- The API is located in: C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flickr_api
- print(flickr_api.**version**) returns the version of flickr_api so it seems my script can at least find the folder?

I'm quite a bgeinner in Python and this is the first time I'm using an API so apologies for an elementary question!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is "How do I get started with the Flickr API for Python?"

I'm using the slightly newer version 2.4 in PyPi, also by Stuvel.  You can find it [here](https://pypi.org/project/flickrapi/).  In this version there is no underscore between flickr and api.

None of the photos in my account uses tags. Instead I'll use a text search.  You should see how the below works and try a tags search.

Also, I'm returning parsed json instead of the default of xml.  The advantage of doing it this way is you get nested dicts, which are pretty easy to parse and loop on in Python.

The following works in Spyder--the interactive shell in Anaconda.  This unsigned call shows my public photos. You should get the same result.

```
import flickrapi

FLICKR_PUBLIC = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

FLICKR_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

flickrapi.__version__
Out[4]: '2.4.0'

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(FLICKR_PUBLIC,FLICKR_SECRET,format='parsed-json')

MYSTUFF = "157919153@N05"

MyAtkinsons = flickr.photos.search(text="Atkinson", 
    user_id = MYSTUFF,
    extras="description")

MyAtkinsons['photos']
Out[8]: 
{'page': 1,
 'pages': 1,
 'perpage': 100,
 'total': '7',
 'photo': [{'id': '50109797342',
   'owner': '157919153@N05',
   'secret': 'a7d95d8c17',
   'server': '65535',
   'farm': 66,
   'title': 'Atkinson, Everett W. and Olive E.',
   'ispublic': 1,
   'isfriend': 0,
   'isfamily': 0,
   'description': {'_content': 'Atkinson, Everett W. and Olive E.'}},
  {'id': '50109558361',
   'owner': '157919153@N05',
   'secret': 'bd2eb4e88f',
   'server': '65535',
   'farm': 66,
   'title': 'Atkinson, Jon Wesley',
   'ispublic': 1,
   'isfriend': 0,
   'isfamily': 0,
   'description': {'_content': 'Atkinson, Jon Wesley'}},
  {'id': '46978210785',
   'owner': '157919153@N05',
   'secret': '299b85c928',
   'server': '65535',
   'farm': 66,
   'title': '17azg7nf6jtz6',
   'ispublic': 1,
   'isfriend': 0,
   'isfamily': 0,
   'description': {'_content': 'Atkinson, Lawrence M.'}},
  {'id': '47105017914',
   'owner': '157919153@N05',
   'secret': 'cfb49d8c5b',
   'server': '65535',
   'farm': 66,
   'title': 'Atkinson, James L. and Florence',
   'ispublic': 1,
   'isfriend': 0,
   'isfamily': 0,
   'description': {'_content': 'Atkinson, James L. and Florence'}},
  {'id': '47104538484',
   'owner': '157919153@N05',
   'secret': '7d52705223',
   'server': '65535',
   'farm': 66,
   'title': '17bcqb9d4n66q',
   'ispublic': 1,
   'isfriend': 0,
   'isfamily': 0,
   'description': {'_content': 'Robbins, Vera M. Atkinson'}},
  {'id': '47893343811',
   'owner': '157919153@N05',
   'secret': 'eed21d5a5c',
   'server': '65535',
   'farm': 66,
   'title': '17be28jy5r95u',
   'ispublic': 1,
   'isfriend': 0,
   'isfamily': 0,
   'description': {'_content': 'Atkinson, Catherine M. and Lew H.'}},
  {'id': '47086890614',
   'owner': '157919153@N05',
   'secret': '1e16987f8b',
   'server': '65535',
   'farm': 66,
   'title': '17bds2q7ui24y',
   'ispublic': 1,
   'isfriend': 0,
   'isfamily': 0,
   'description': {'_content': 'Atkinson, James'}}]}
```

I have seven photos of Atkinsons in my account that are available to the public as of today.

If you need tags, add that to the extras parameter.  I just use the default resolution of my photos parsed from the 'id', so I don't request the URL in the extras parameter.